# Set position of element using .show() command in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to amend .show() command in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/show/) so that instead of showing the div in its original position, the div appears at the bottom of a list of divs ?

Comment: You not necessary need to amend the show() function. If you can just move the div to the desired position then call show() function. If you provide me some html I can give you a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Yes, but I would rather create an extra function/plugin method. There might be cases where you want the original functionality of `show`.

Comment: I would help, but I'm not quite sure what you're wanting? Are you wanting a hidden div to get shown using the jquery command .show() at a different location where it actually is?

Comment: I'd provide offset to the div before calling the Show function.

Comment: You can also extend jQuery with your custom function called e.g. showAtBottom() that moves the selected jquery object(s) to the bottom of their container then shows them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/PqLXF/

Here is the code -

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainDiv">

<div>One</div>
<div class="showthisdiv">Two</div>
<div>Three</div>
<div>Four</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.showthisdiv{
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.showthisdiv').show().insertAfter('.mainDiv div:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do more:

```
$('#your_element').show('slow', function() {
    $('#your_element').css(USE CSS TO POSITION YOUR DIV ELEMENT);
  });
```

or, like @Dipak Suryavanshi suggested

```
$('#your_element').show('slow', function() {
    $('#your_element').insertAfter('.mainDiv div:last');​
  });
```

the power of this solution s that you can do anything with your element (just add code in the function).